# Siunitx installation: I can't find file l3docstrip.tex

Tags: installing, siunitx, latex3

I have some problem trying to compile `siunitx`.
When I do `latex siunitx.dtx`, I get the following message:

```
! I can't find file `l3docstrip.tex'.
l.77 \input l3docstrip.tex
```

Where am I supposed to find it? I have installed both `l3kernel` and
`l3packages` as indicated in the README.
By the way, I have a working older version of `siunitx` installed; I noticed this issue when I wanted to install siunitx from the latest sources on another computer.

Comment: why not update the whole distribution using the relevant package manager? [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: Although it's possible, I strongly recommend people don't unpack code themselves but rather use their package manager or `.tds.zip` files for installation. Of course, I am willing to get you sorted: as I say it is quite possible to do this unpacking yourself, if a bit tedious. To give more help, I'll need to know the version of `l3kernel` you have.

Comment: I have not complete control on the said computer so the update is not really an option (though that would probably be the best).

I use just downloaded l3kernel from ctan.

If that's tedious then I could as well  copy my old version from on computer to another or use a `.tds.zip`. I did not knew where to find the latter and thought it did not make a huge difference. I have found it now.

Comment: I need to check if the latest `.tds.zip` has the file placed correctly: if not I'll adjust our build script for the next (imminent) CTAN snapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I want to recommend an update of the whole distribution. Most packages have some decencies and so a single update of a `sty` file isn't sufficient. To update the whole distribution see *[How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)*

Instead of compiling the `dtx` file you can use the sty files directly. As mentioned by Joseph you can download every package as `<packagename>.tds.zip`. These archive has the default texmf tree structure.

```
packagename.tds.zip
    |
    |-doc
    |   |-latex
    |       |-packagename
    |
    |-source
    |   |-latex
    |       |-packagename
    |
    |-tex
        |-latex
            |-packagename
```

In the path `tex->latex->packagename` you will find the relevant `sty` file(s).

The correct `tds.zip` archive can be found by using the following link:

- http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/

Comment: please don't point direct at archive servers (they are there as the centre of a network of mirrors, not as mirrors themselves).  the correct address for a tds file would be [http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/pkg.tds.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/pkg.tds.zip)

Comment: @wasteofspace: Changed. Thanks. I didn't find the correct link ;-)